# jquery conditional - check class="" and input type=""

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am pretty new to jquery/javascript and pretty much have to dig for an hour to write what i need, so in an attempt to save time, i am trying to write a conditional statement to check the class of an element and also that the "type" attribute is "text". This statement worked when I was just chacking .hasClass, and brok when adding && .is('[text]'). Is my syntax wrong? I have this, but it is not working:

```
if(!$("input").hasClass("input-block-level") && .is('[text]')) {
     $("input").addClass("input-block-level");
}
```

my reason for doing this is that we have input fields that are dynamically added via python and TMPL_VAR. This is just a band-aid until the other team member can get the python script changed, but also as a fall back if we miss it somewhere else :)

Comment: First of all, yes, syntax is wrong. You can't start anything with a `.`. Second, I'm unsure what you're trying to do here. Are you trying to make sure that all input's that are of type `text=""` (which isn't a property on input in the first place) get's the property 'input-block-level'? In what context is this code run?

Comment: To answer your question, even though I have found a working solution...I am building a template for a proprietary real estate product. some of the inputs i have control over, and some are fed from the server in the python script which means i cannot add the appropriate css class to them as the are added to my template with CPAN - <!-- TMPL_VAR first_name ESCAPE=0 -->. So i needed a script that would check if an input[type=text] had a class assigned to it, if not then assign one. Make Sense?

Answer (score 3):

You might want to change the condition to this :

```
var $input = $("input");
if($input.hasClass("input-block-level") && $input.is('input:text')) { 
  //your code
}
```

Or, you could change your selector to get elements of `type=text` alone :

```
var $input = $("input[type=text]");
if($input.hasClass("input-block-level")) {
 //your code 
}
```

Another good way to do this is using `filter` :

```
$("input[type=text]").filter(":not(.input-block-level)").addClass("input-block-level");
```

Answer (score 2):

The addClass() method adds the class, but it won't duplicate it. You can go with:

```
$("input[type='text']").addClass('input-block-level');
```

The function will cycle through all text input elements and adds the class. It's a good solution if you have a lot of inputs.

The addClass method will check if the element has the class on it's own, you don't need to check it before.

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand you are trying to add a class `input-block-level` to `input` elements which does not have the class and has type `text`

a simple one liner will do

```
$('input:text').not('.input-block-level').addClass("input-block-level");
```

Comment: `.not('.input-block-level')` is not obligatory here, the `addClass()` checks if the element already has the class.

Comment: @Binkley have a look at [this performance profile](http://jsperf.com/addclass-vs-not-addclass) to checkout the difference http://jsperf.com/addclass-vs-not-addclass

Comment: yea definitely faster

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you looking for?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7g8mR/1/)

```
if(!$("input:text").hasClass("input-block-level")) {
    $("input:text").addClass("input-block-level");
}
```